# Create df aggregating from multiple rows into single row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm working with an events dataset and need help in creating a new df by summing a specific variable based on certain conditions.

For example, lets say I had a dataset of all cars sold in a county with the name of the dealership, the month the car was sold, the year the car was sold, and the number of cars sold for the past *n* years. I want to create a new df where each row would present the number of cars sold by a particular dealership at the year level.

In other words, I want to go from something like this:

```
Dealership   Month    Year    # of Cars
Bobs         April    2016    12
Toms         March    2016    8
Bobs         July     2016    20
Toms         June     2016    4
...
```

To

```
Dealership   Month    Year    # of Cars
Bobs         ?        2016    32
Toms         ?        2016    12
...
```

I'm not sure if that will give me an error because the month data (or other columns in a bigger dataset) will be different. I just don't need that information.

Can anyone help? Many thanks.

Comment: We need to see more.  You say "I'm not sure if that will give me an error..."  Try it, post your code for it and what the results were.  We need an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

We can only do so much without a reproducible example, but this is probably covered by [dplyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/summarise)

```
library(dplyr)
yourdata %>% group_by(Dealership, Year) %>% summarise(Ncars = sum(`# of Cars`))
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Thank you. The dataset I'm using is <http://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/ged/ged40-csv.zip>. It's an event data on armed conflict that uses media reports to identify incidents of violence (down to a day and time) in armed conflict. The key variables I'm most interested in the dataset are conflict_new_id (dealership), deaths_civilians (# of cars), and year (Year). There are often thousands of rows for each belligerent from 1989-2014. I apologize that It's not a reproducible example but I'm fairly new to this. Any help is greatly appreciated.